# How to display date value from sfWidgetFormDate?(symfony1.4)

Tags: php, date, calendar, symfony-1.4

I am new to symfony and have a nasty problem:

How to display date value from sfWidgetFormDate?

**My Form**

```
public function configure()
{
 $this->setWidget('BIRTH_DATE', new sfWidgetFormDate());
 $this->setWidget('NICKNAME', new sfWidgetFormInput());
}
```

**Front Page**

```
foreach(){
  echo $values[$key];//$key='NICKNAME'   $key='BIRTH_DATE'
}
```

'NICKNAME' can be displayed, but 'BIRTH_DATE' can not.
If I change sfWidgetFormDate() into sfWidgetFormInput(), 'BIRTH_DATE' can be displayed.

It is too strange, I don't know why.

**Thank you ilSavo, you are the only one who comment for the problem.**

**And I still need someone's help!**

Comment: Aren't you saving the form values to an entity?! I guess you should first save your form values, and then display the data. If not, please try to update your question

Comment: Hi ilSavo, yes I haved saved form values, the other values I can get, I will update question, please watch again, thank you.

Comment: Now, I guess you are saving the data in a DB. are you sure the data are correctly saved? And then, which way are you retrieving the data? what's there in your foreach?

Comment: Thank you ilSavo, I used sfWidgetFormSelect() to make a Date Function instead of sfWidgetFormDate().